# MIC ON, Problems with audio on IOS 15

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, sound-volume

I ask for help with this problem, example: In a game or any app, I turn on the microphone and automatically the audio/sound of background apps slide the volume or mute or switch to MONO. Example: In games, we need STEREO audio to hear directions and we also need the microphone to talk to the team (Squad). It is not possible, with the microphone connected, the game audio will switch to MONO! MY QUESTION: Is there any app to manage and control audio output for iPhone?

I came across the same problem on the following devices: IPhone 8Plus IOS 14.8, IPhone XR IOS 15.1. and iPhone 12 IOS 15.1

*[From Google Translate. original below]*

---

Oi, peço ajuda com esse problema, exemplo: Em um jogo ou em qualquer aplicativo, ligo o microfone e automaticamente o áudio/som dos aplicativos em segundo plano deslizo o volume ou mudo ou mude para MONO. Exemplo: Nos jogos, precisamos de áudio ESTÉREO para ouvir direções e também precisamos do microfone para conversar com a equipe (Esquadrão). Não é possível, com o microfone conectado, o áudio do jogo mudará para MONO! MINHA PERGUNTA: Existe algum aplicativo para gerenciar e controlar a saída de áudio para iPhone?

Me deparei com o mesmo problema nos seguintes dispositivos: IPhone 8Plus IOS 14.8, IPhone XR IOS 15.1. e iPhone 12 IOS 15.1

Comment: Please use only English on this site. I've added a Google Translate to your question. Can you check it for accuracy?

Comment: Are you using Bluetooth headsets or wired?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can find out, the iPhone's mics are not set to be stereo by default. Usually, the connection from a wired or bluetooth mic to an iPhone is for telephony, which does not require a stereo audio signal.

[This page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/capturing_stereo_audio_from_built-in_microphones) at Apple Developer shows how to enable stereo microphone input, but only, it seems, from within an iOS app coded to do so. I've seen no Setting in iOS to change to Stereo.

An [iPhone feedback submission](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone/) to Apple may be a first step making Apple aware of the necessity of providing user control of the built-in mics.

Comment: I doubt the OP means stereo input, only output. BT telephony is mono out, as opposed to 'hifi' which is stereo, hence my 'is it BT?' query.

Comment: thank you!  It helped a lot!  I've already sent feedback to Apple!  Mobile Gamer (IPhone) has thousands of users with the same problem.  It could be an opportunity to create an app that solves this problem!